# LineSeries with intervals

Tags: lightweight-charts

I was wondering if there exists a way in which, while using a LineSeries, to draw the line in intervals and not drawing the parts on which there is no data. For example, right now I have something like this:

[image]

there are places in which there is no data for the yellow line, and I would like to not draw the line over those. In this case, where the big red column is, there is no data for the yellow line. I would like to do something like this:

[image]

Is there a functionality that works like this or enables me to do this?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not available right now out of the box, but you could track [this issue](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/699) to be notified when it will be done.

As a workaround you could create several separate lines, but this is not so convenient though.

Comment: The proposed workaround would be adding multiple LineSeries to the same chart, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.